# String as object method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to use a string to call a method on an object. For instance with a string `foo = 'bar'`, how could I call `bar` on the class `Baz`: `Baz.bar`. An alternative would be to create a case statement like this;

```
case foo
when 'bar'
  Baz.bar
when 'qux'
  Baz.qux
end
```

Comment: Hi @mu-is-too-short, I was googling for a while to find a solution and the suggested duplicate never came up. I assume it never came up because it's referring to methods as functions. I appreciate that the answer is the same but hopefully this question will save a dev some time in the future. Either that or update the duplicate question to use the term "method" instead, especially in the title so it comes up on searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call just any method on an object with `send`:

```
foo = 'bar'
Baz.send(foo) // calls bar on Baz
```

This calls private methods, too. If you only want to call public methods use `public_send`:

```
foo = 'bar'
Baz.public_send(foo) // calls only public method bar on Baz
```

If you want to check if a public method is defined, you can use `respond_to?`

```
foo = 'bar'
if Baz.respond_to?(foo)
  // only gets executed if public method bar is defined on Baz
  Baz.send(foo) // executes bar on Baz
end
```

If you want to also check private methods you have to provide `true` as second arg:

```
Baz.respond_to?(foo, true)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was googling for ages but I didn't know what I should be searching for :+1: